# Take data from IList instead of IEnumerable (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, list, ienumerable

when I got:

```
public interface Test
{
    IEnumerable<Guid> ModelIds { get; set; }
}
```

Then into service I have:

```
public IEnumerable<Guid> Test
{
    get => m_data.ModelIds;
    set { m_data.ModelIds = value.ToList(); }
}
```

And then I'm using it like:

```
abc.ModelIds = my_list.Select(x => x.Id);
```

But I need to make change into interface:

```
public interface Test
{
    IList<Guid> ModelIds { get; set; }
}
```

and implementation service:

```
public IList<Guid> Test
```

And now how to take the id?

```
abc.ModelIds = my_list.Select(x => x.Id);
```

> error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Guid>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<System.Guid>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: `Select(x => x.Id).ToList()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is here.

```
public IEnumerable<Guid> Test
{
   get => m_data.ModelIds;
   set { m_data.ModelIds = value.ToList(); }
}
```

Instead of .ToList() just use m_data.ModelIds = value;

If it says problem is here.

```
abc.ModelIds = my_list.Select(x => x.Id);
```

Try

```
 abc.ModelIds = my_list.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
```